# Ruby on rails : Rspec installation guidance and usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Anyone guide me to installing rspec in ror and need to know the usage.

Give me if you know any simple links..

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a replacement for Google.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) link. There is a good wiki and a lot of examples how to configure and user rcpec.